# WordPress Facebook comments error "Can't download"

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins

I want Facebook comments on my images on WordPress. I'm using the Social Gallery Lite plugin for WordPress.  It shows a comment lightbox for each image.

I have two problems:

- The comments are not appearing in my moderation tool / I'm not getting notifications of new comments
- Every time I add a new comment, I get an errormessage saying "Can't download", nothing more.  When I refresh, the comment is added.  When I add another comment on the same image, I don't get any errors.  When I add another comment on another image, I get the error again.

This is what I did:

1. installed and acitvated the plugin
2. created a new app on facebook
3. copy pasted the APP ID in my plugin
4. made sure that I am the admin of the app
5. published the app (not even sure if this was necessary)

Am I missing a step?

Comment: you should rather ask the creator of the plugin, stackoverflow is for developers only. you would have to come up with more than just "i did the steps and it does not work" ;) debug the code, check out the browser console, stuff like that...

Comment: I have asked the creator, but they said I should just add the APP ID and use the moderation tool.  But it does not work.  I tried searching for documentation on google, but most documentation that I find is dated and the UI has changed.  It is also very "general" and not focussed on my situation.  Then I wanted to ask facebook, but they recommended this forum.

Comment: But I do respect if this is the wrong platform and will understand if the moderator removes my topic.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a coding related question here. So possibly on the wrong forum, best asked on the Wordpress community.

However, will attempt an answer here, it would seem that on the plugin itself does not need a facebook app to be created [screenshot for app ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Grpx.png), it has a native app to do that. What you need to do is to provide your admin ID to the plugin to access your comments [screenshot for admin access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajpWJ.png).

Comment: I will try the Wordpress community, thanks.

Also thank you for your response.  Admin ID is for editing/deleting comments.  I set that already and that part works.  The APP ID is for moderating comments and getting notifications, that part, I still cannot get to work.